# At the lowest level, can mathematical proofs be reduced to substitutions and rewrites?

Tags: logic, foundations

This is the impression I got from reading Douglas Hofstadter's book, Godel, Escher, Bach.  He spoke of being able to design a proof checker that applied axioms and theorems to determine if a statement followed from the previous ones. It reminded me of using BNF to check the syntax of statements in a programming language.

Comment: Yes. However, this would be impractical for all but the simplest propositions, and the utility of doing it for simple propositions is questionable!

Comment: As an aside, formal proof checking is used in digital IC design to verify conformance of behaviours with specifications. Funded my behaviours for a while :-).

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen [metamath](http://us.metamath.org/)? It is a formalization of a large amount of mathematics in an extremely simple system:

> Metamath uses a single, simple [substitution rule](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/mmset.html#proofs) that allows you to follow any proof mechanically.

The deduction rules are so simple that they can be (and are) checked by computer.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the Metamath package also comes with a file implementing the simple MIU system Hofstadter introduced in Godel Escher Bach.